# .net framework to .net 5 migration build but does not launch

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, .net-5

I just migrated my .net Framework 4.8 project into a .net 5 one.

First I changed the old csproj project configuration file to the new one. Then deleted the redundant assembly and finally delete or update all the package. After that I launched the project compatibility test to see if all my project was compatible with .net 5 and launch the project.

Weirdly and without more details the project build (I have an .exe), launch and close itself immediately and the only clue I have is this message:

```
The target process terminated without raising a CoreCLR start event. Make sure the target process is 
configured to use .NET Core. This can be expected behavior if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
Program 'test.exe' terminated with code -2147450740 (0x8000808c).
The program 'test.exe: Program trace' has stopped with code 0 (0x0).
```

part of my csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>    
     <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
```

does somebody have an idea of what gone wrong?

Comment: How do you run the test.exe? Are you just launching the test.exe directly?

Comment: Check net 5 sdk and runtimes installed.

Comment: I launched test.exe with visual studio and I also tried to launch it directly but nothing happens, the window does not show. 

I have the latest version of .net 5 SDK installed

Comment: Did you try to create a new .NET 5 project and added the existing items from the old project to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted my demo project named **FrameworkToNet5** which target framework4.7 to .Net 5 in below steps, and it is successful, hope it will be some help for you to refer to:

**Step 1:** Create a framework WPF project named **FrameworkToNet5** in Visual studio 16.8.1, and install `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf` in the Nuget package.

**Step 2:** To enable the designer, go to Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features and select the Use the preview Windows Forms designer for .NET Core apps option.

**Step 3:** Right click **FrameworkToNet5**, go `Analyze and Code Cleanup`,Click `Run Code Analysis` to check for .Net 5.

**Step 4:** Right-click on `packages.config` > `Migrate packages.config to PackageReference`, then Select all of the `top-level` packages.

**Step 5:** Use below code to replace the .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf" Version="1.1.19" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**Step 6:** Use below code to replace the content for AssemblyInfo.cs

```
using System.Windows;
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, 
ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly )]
```

**Step 7:** Clean and rebuild the project.